# How can set "Shift + Click" on VBA Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to set an Open FileDialog on a text-field via "Shift+Click" (Shift key + click of mouse like left click), how is it possible?

I wrote this for Open File Dialog :

```
Private Sub Article_Click()
    Dim dialog As FileDialog
    Set dialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With dialog
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    Me.Article() = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With 
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this help? http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/run-an-access-macro-by-using-a-keyboard-shortcut-HA010239111.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `MouseDown` event of the Text Box to determine the state of the <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, and <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys using the technique described here:

[Detecting SHIFT, CTRL, and ALT States](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716234%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

In your case, if you only care about the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key then you could use something like this:

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Dim ShiftTest As Integer

Private Sub Article_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
   ShiftTest = Shift And 1
End Sub

Private Sub Article_Click()
    If ShiftTest = 1 Then
        Dim dialog As FileDialog
        Set dialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        With dialog
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            .Show
            Me.Article() = .SelectedItems(1)
        End With 
    End If
End Sub
```